# Is this statement about limits with periodic function true?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, periodic-functions

Here is the statement :

> Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function and $g$ a
> non constant periodic function in any open intervals of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\lim_{x\to +\infty} g(f(x))= l \in \mathbb{R}$. Then $\lim_{x\to +\infty} f(x) = l' \in \mathbb{R}$.

For instance if I take $g \equiv \cos$ the statement is true.

For the general case I have no clue... Probably if the periodic function checks the bijection's theorem it seems to work.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You need an additional assumption: if $g$ is constant (hence periodic), then the statement is wrong.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Indeed good remark !

Comment: You need at least $g$ not-constant in any open interval. Otherwise, you can build counterexamplex as well

Comment: I think that if you assume in addition $g$ to be continuous and non-constant in any open interval, then the statement becomes true.

Comment: I think the statement is true, if $g$ is non-constant in any open intervall, but I don't see why $g$ has to be continuous. It just has to "see" every oscilation of $f$ and that exactly means, that it's non-constant on intervalls

Comment: Actually, one doesn’t even need continuity

Comment: @LorenzoPompili Thank you for the suggestions ! I'll try to write a proof adding the fact that $g$ has to be non constant in any open intervals of $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous s.t. $\lim_{x \to \infty} g(f(x))$ exists. Let $p>0$ be a periodic of $g$, i.e. $g(x+p)=g(x)$ for all $x$ s.t. $g$ is not constant on any non-trivial intervall.

First notice that $f$ doesn't divergence to $+ \infty$ (or $- \infty$). Assume $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = + \infty$. Let $x_1 > f(0)$ and $x_2>f(0)$ s.t. $g(x_1) \neq g(x_2)$.

Let $(y_n)_n$ be a sequence s.t. $f(y_{2n})=x_1+np$ and $f(y_{2n+1})=x_2+np$. This is possible by the intermediate value theorem applied to $f$. Since $f$ is bounded on compact sets, $\lim_n y_n= \infty$. However, $g(f(y_{2n}))=g(x_1)$ and $g(f(y_{2n+1}))=g(x_2)$, hence $g(f(y_n))$ diverges, which is a contradiction.

If $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ doesn't exist in $[-\infty,+\infty]$, there are $a<b$ and sequences $(x_n)_n \to \infty$ and $(y_n)_n \to \infty$ s.t. $f(x_n)=a$ and $f(y_n)=b$ for all $n$. By passing to subsequences we can assume $x_1 <y_1 <x_2 < y_2 < ...$

If $g(a) \neq g(b)$, this is a contradiction to the existence of $\lim_{x \to \infty} g(f(x))$.

Otherwise, we can find $c \in (a,b)$ s.t. $g(c) \neq g(a)$, since $g$ isn't constant on intervalls. By the intermediate value theorem applied to $f$ we ge a sequence $(z_n)_n$ s.t. $x_1<y_1<z_1<x_2<y_2<z_2<...$ and $f(z_n)=c$. This yields the same contradiction to the existence of $\lim_{x \to \infty} g(f(x))$.